# Having some trouble with the logic in my Javascript pagination code

Tags: javascript, pagination

```
function Browse()
{
    this.offset = 10;
}

/*
 * @direction is either 'next' or 'prev'
 */
Browse.prototype.loadMore = function(direction)
{
    var _this = this;

    $.getJSON('/path/to/api?offset=' + this.offset, function(json)
    {
        _this.offset = (direction == 'next') ? _this.offset + 10 : _this.offset - 10;

        if (_this.offset > 10)
            previousButton.show();
        else
            previousButton.hide();
    });
}
```

This is the basic code. The user clicks a link which triggers `loadMore()`. This function pulls down the JSON data starting at the `offset`.

This offset will change based on their current 'page'. The first page will have a 0 offset. Second page will be 10. Third page 20, etc...

As they navigate back and forth, this offset should change accordingly. The problem is, it isn't. I can't see why...

Any ideas?

Comment: You are using `new Browse()` and hooking the instance's `loadMore` method, yes?

Comment: Yeah, it's all being called correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the ajax call takes time to execute.

Try:

```
//...
var _this = this;

$.getJSON('/path/to/api?offset=' + this.offset, function(json) {
  //...
});
_this.offset = (direction == 'next') ? _this.offset + 10 : _this.offset - 10;
//...
```

This will use the right value in your ajax call, and change the offset ready for the next call before the ajax call returns. You might want to add logic to ignore the return value from the ajax call if the offset has been adjusted in the mean time.